# Define a function that will perform various tasks, but terminates with a certain input

Tags: python, function, if-statement

```
def main():
    choice = pickone() #picking the shape or to quit
    if choice not in quitlist:

        low, high = getLoHiInt() #picking the range of points

        shapes = [ball,bowlingPin,ellipse,tableLeg]

        combolist = zip(picklist,shapes) #zipped list of the shapes with the corresponding choice

        analyzeSolid(combolist[int(choice)-1][1], low, high)

    return showTermination()
```

the pickone() function works just fine, the problem is when I type the terminate number my function show the termination but continues through the if loop even though the choice is in the quitlist.

```
quitlist = ['5']
```

Unfortunately I need it this way because other parts of my code depend on this. I also need my if statement to restart at the pickone() function after it goes through the if statement, but it just shows my termination instead and end the program.

since some say my pickone function doesn't work fine

```
picklist = ["1","2","3","4"]
quitlist = ["5"] #couldn't get it to work with just one list, but this works fine
def pickone():
    while True:
        print "\nPick a solid to analyze: \n1: ball\n2: bowlingPin\n3: ellipse\n4: tableleg\n5: quit"
        theinput = raw_input("What is the number of your choice?: ")
        #if theinput not in zip(picklist, quitlist):
        #    print"\nChoice %s is not a valid choice.\n" %theinput
        try:
            theinput
        except ValueError:
            # So the program will continue if the input is wrong
            print "choice must be from 1 to 5" #message doesn't show up but the program still works properly
            continue
        if theinput in picklist:
            return theinput
        if theinput in quitlist:
            return theinput
```

Edit, there was a problem with my pickone function, it should have returned theinput not showTermination()

Comment: The `pickone()` function probably *doesn't* "work fine", but since you don't show it to us, there's no way for us to know (hint: odds are you're returning on integer, not a string, from that function but your `quitlist` has a string).

Comment: You are talking about this in a way that no one here could possibly understand. I count 13 identifiers we can only guess at the value or the implementation of. Can you simplify this to something that just shows whatever you are asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to make a menu like this

```
def do_menu(menu,error="Invalid Choice Try Again!"):
    while True:
        for k,(msg,action) in menu.items():
            print msg
        resp = raw_input("Make a Choice:")
        if resp in menu:
            return menu[resp][1]()
        print error

import random,sys

#####JUST SOME GENERIC MENU ACTIONS
something = []

def add_something():
    something.append(random.randint(1,10))
    print "ADDED %d"%something[-1]

def print_something():
    print something

#DEFINE THE MENU
menu = {
'A':("[A]dd Something",add_something),
'P':("[P]rint Something",print_something),
'Q':("[Q]uit",sys.exit)
}
while True:
    #print menu and get user response and act upon it
    print "\n#####[ MENU ]####"
    result = do_menu(menu)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to obtain a loop which would continue until termination you might try something like:

```
def main():
    choice = pickone() #picking the shape or to quit
    while choice not in quitlist:

        low, high = getLoHiInt() #picking the range of points

        shapes = [ball,bowlingPin,ellipse,tableLeg]

        combolist = zip(picklist,shapes) #zipped list of the shapes with the corresponding choice

        analyzeSolid(combolist[int(choice)-1][1], low, high)

        choice = pickone()
    return showTermination()
```

in order to figure out why your loop is continuing though you choose a quit value, try printing out what is in `choice`, perhaps it is getting an `integer` value and not a `string`?

if that is the case, maybe try:

```
choice = str(pickone())
```

or

```
while str(choice) not in quitlist:
    ...
```